# Can't remove top padding or space in table-cell, why?

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm adding padding to my left table cell but center and right cell also gets top padding. How do I remove padding from center and right cell?

the center and right cells are still top padded.

http://jsfiddle.net/o50s8ucj/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .left, .center, .right {
                display: table-cell;
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
            }

            .center, .right {
                display: table-cell;
                width: 100px;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .left {
                padding: 10px;
                background: yellow;
            }

            .center {
                background: pink;
            }

            .right {
                background: orange;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="left">a</div>
        <div class="center">b</div>
        <div class="right">c</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which padding do you want removed from the centre and right cells?

Comment: Yes, the center and right one. As it appears, they inherit the top padding for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you want is to use `vertical-align:top;`

```
.left, .center, .right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o50s8ucj/2/

Comment: That does the trick. The solution doesn't make the sense, though. That lovely CSS. Thanks.

Comment: The browser is trying to keep the text aligned when you use `table-cell`.  Another alternative is to use `float: left` instead of `display: table-cell`.  http://jsfiddle.net/o50s8ucj/1/

Comment: You can also see a more in-depth explanation of `vertical-align` [here](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/).

Answer (score 1):

When executed in the fiddle shared by you, it is padded only in the left and center,right remains without padding

Comment: The top is still padded. Play with the fiddle and remove padding from the left cell, and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add text-align: center and vertical-align : middle property to your class .left, .center and .right.

see this JS fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/4gnrnwka/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace **display:table-cell** with **display:inline-block** the padding on top of the center and right rectangles is eliminated as follows:

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        /*padding: 0;*/
    }

    .left, .center, .right {

        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .center, .right {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .left {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
        background: yellow;
    }

    .center {
        background: pink;
    }

    .right {
        background: orange;
    }
```

Also see http://jsfiddle.net/o50s8ucj/6/

Answer (score 0):

Only the left cell is getting top padding, center and right cells are padding-free.